# Julia: When to type true or false in DifferentialEquations systems?

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I'm drawing inspiration from the source code of [DiffEqFinancial.jl](https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqFinancial.jl/blob/master/src/problems.jl) to properly set up my own system. I do not understand the purpose of `true` and `false` in the code snippets below:

```
sde_f = SDEFunction{true}(f,g)

SDEProblem{false}(f,g,u0,tspan;kwargs...)
```

So what do `{true}` and `{false}` do in this context?

I'd like to know if I should have it in my own user code too. I am vaguely aware of the adage to "strictly type types, loosely type functions," so I wonder why the typing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few hours after posting my question, I found the answer by the author himself, Chris Rackauckas. Quote:

> if you are creating thousands of really small ODEProblems and want to
> avoid the dynamic checking going on, then you should do
> ODEProblem{false}(...) or ODEProblem{true}(...), i.e. directly declare
> whether it’s in in-place or out-of-place form. Normally this isn’t a
> huge deal so it’s not mentioned very often in the documentation, but
> it’s in there since there are scenarios where this helps.

Source: [Chris Rackauckas](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-the-separation-of-odeproblem-and-solve-in-differentialequations-jl/43737/2)

Comment: Yes, you can think of this parameter value as the answer to the question "Is `f` in-place?".

Comment: Merci Benoît!  :-)